# Reducing crosstab size by frequency of responses

Tags: r

Excuse my neophyte question - I'm new to R and pretty unversed in statistics.

I have a simple contingency table representing the number of queries per user for a group of web pages gathered over a period of time. There are about 15,000 total observations. This works out to a table of around 100 users viewing 50 groups of pages.

Since a 50x100 matrix is unwieldy to visualize, I would like to present a subset of this table sorted by the largest aggregates - either column (page groups), row (users), or perhaps even the largest row-by-column counts. For example I might choose the top 20 users and the top 10 groups, or the top 99% row-by-column counts.

Ideally, I end up with a table that still represents the major interactions between the most represented users and the page groups.

Is this a reasonable approach? Will I lose some large amount of statistical significance; and, is there a way to compare the before and after significance.

I must admit that I still don't know how to sort and subset a table based on two factors without resorting to row-by-column manipulation.

Comment: Take a look at the [stats.se](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) site -- your question might be a better fit there. If you think so, flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it for you.

Comment: (oh, wait, flagging requires more points than you've got so far -- just reply with `@sarnold` in a comment and I'll happily cast the flag for you if you wish.)

Comment: Looks like a perfectly R-computable problem. What's missing is the code to produce the sample problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
S <- trunc(10*runif(1000) )
R <- trunc(10*runif(1000))
RStab <- table(R, S)
str(RStab)
# 'table' int [1:10, 1:10] 6 12 10 13 10 7 8 6 9 10 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ R: chr [1:10] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
#  ..$ S: chr [1:10] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
 rowSums( RStab[ order(rowSums(RStab)) , order(colSums(RStab) ) ]) 
#  8   0   1   3   2   5   9   4   6   7 
# 90  94  96  99 100 101 101 103 107 109 
colSums( RStab[ order(rowSums(RStab)) , order(colSums(RStab) ) ])
  6   0   3   5   7   2   4   8   9   1 
 80  91  94  96  98 100 106 109 112 114
```

The 5 highest marginals for row and columns:

```
RStab[ order(rowSums(RStab)) , order(colSums(RStab) ) ][ 6:10, 6:10]
#-------------
   S
R    2  4  8  9  1
  5 14 10 12 10 12
  9  6  8  9 10 13
  4 10 10  8  8 18
  6  9 12 12 17  8
  7 14 10 14 12  9
```

It does sound as though you might be a little shakey on the statistical issues. Can you explain more fully what you mean by "losing a large amount of significance"? What sort of statistical test were you thinking of?

Comment: @sarnold - Thanks for the pointer to the [link](stats.se) site - I was able to immediately find a good example of what I was trying to do. No need to cross-post, but thanks for the offer.

Comment: yes, I am shakey. Most of my knowledge comes from social psych studies about 40 years ago - and that was just as a CS student. Thank you very much for the excellent example - it is directly applicable to what I need.